# Regex to spilt the string with the occurance of matching group

Tags: c#, regex

The string is "India Delhi, UK London, US Newyork (except Los Angeles), Europe France (except Paris)"

I want to spilt the given string in the way that it gives me the result as follows:

```
`string str ="India Delhi, UK London, US Newyork (except Los Angeles), Europe France (except Paris)"
 match.Groups[1].Value = "India Delhi, UK London, US Newyork"
 match.Groups[2].Value = "Los Angeles"
 match.Groups[3].Value = "Europe France"
 match.Groups[4].Value = "Paris"`
```

Any leads on this would be appreciable?

Comment: https://regex101.com/  Though, I'd parse the tokens based on `,` first and then extract the parts I wanted from the tokens. You are encouraged to start writing your [mcve].

Comment: What are the criteria for splitting up the items? How do you know that three cities go in the first spot, but only one in the second spot, etc?

Comment: You could use Regexe's `Split` method, but the problem is with the last parenthesis. To overcome this problem, you need to strip out last string: `string pattern = @" \(except |\), |\)"; var matches = Regex.Split(input, pattern).Where(m => m != "");`

Comment: @JohnyL It works! Thank you

Comment: @user3286359 Can't make full answer because it's put on hold 

Answer (score 1):

This is a little weird requirement but this regex works for your requirement. Matching and capturing the text would be better than split as your expected output shows some parts truncated from the input text.

```
[A-Z][\w ]+(?:, [\w ]+)*
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7IZerr/1)**

Here is a C# sample codes,

```
string input1 = "India Delhi, UK London, US Newyork (except Los Angeles), Europe France (except Paris)";
var m1 = Regex.Matches(input1, @"[A-Z][\w ]+(?:, [\w ]+)*");
foreach (Match match in m1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Which prints the output as you expected,

```
India Delhi, UK London, US Newyork 
Los Angeles
Europe France 
Paris
```

Answer (score -3):

The following linq should work

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<string>> groups = new List<List<string>>() {
                new List<string>() { "India Delhi", "UK London", "US Newyork"},
                new List<string>() { "Los Angeles" },
                new List<string>() { "Europe France"},
                new List<string>() { "Paris"}
            };


            string input = "India Delhi, UK London, US Newyork, Europe France";

            var results = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(x => x.Trim()).SelectMany(x => groups.Select((y, i) => new { str = x, truth = y.Contains(x), group = i }))
                .Where(x => x.truth == true)
                .GroupBy(x => x.group)
                .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.str).ToList())
                .ToList();
        }
```